# Serge Lang - Basic Mathematics - Sum of Binomial coefficients p.387 ex. 9

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I can not understand the solution.How does the second step come about? How does the expression in brackets appear?

[solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCQHB.png)

Comment: $ab + ac = a[b+c]$ :-)

Comment: yeah, I know, but here it is somehow not obvious to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note:

$$(n - k + 1)! = (n-k)! \cdot (n - k + 1)$$

$$k! = (k-1)! \cdot k$$

Rewrite the expression after the first equal sign with this in mind: you should see a common factor you can neatly factor out.

Comment: thanks! the problem was that the first property was not clear to me